# Same program, same JVM, but vastly different memory requirements and execution time on different machines - why?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory, execution-time

I'm trying to run a [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) (a java simulation framework) simulation on a cluster as part of a large experiment. I was surprised at the seemingly massive memory requirement of a (relatively) simple simulation. On the cluster it throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exceptions for anything less than "-Xmx2500M" heapsizes. A single execution takes 5 hours to run. I ran the same experiment on both my Macs (iMac and MacBook Pro), and they executed in less than one hour, with "-Xmx1024" giving no errors. The cluster jobs require "-XX:MaxPermSize=250M" whereas on my Macs no increase above default is required. I ran the same code, the same inputs, using the exact same jars in all cases.

64 bit JVMs are used in each case (and as far as I know these are pretty similar):

```
<on the cluster>
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

<on my macs>
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-10M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
```

And I am running Client JVM in all cases (was initially using Server on cluster, switching to client made no difference). I have tried executing on the cluster with java 7, same huge memory and execution time issues.

I am completely perplexed, no one I have spoken to can explain this. Has anyone out there come across this before? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should create a heap dump with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and then using MAT or similar to see what's using up the memory.

Comment: I would use VisualVM or a commercial memory profiler like YourKit.

Comment: looks to me like you also have two different jvm versions.  Not saying it's your issue, but it could contribute.

Comment: Thanks all, I shall examine heap dumps. @Matt: you are correct, they are slightly different. However I tried both java 6 and 7 JVMs, and they both gave the same issue. I would find it very strange if the Macs were running a JVM that needed less than half the RAM to run the same job.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect one has faster network or disk IO.  If you are using queues to write to the disk or write to the network where one computer can keep up and but the other cannot, the queue might grow slowing the machine and using an unlimited amount of memory.

If you have faster network IO it can either help send data faster (keeping queues small), or it can mean you receive data too fast (meaning queue can grow faster than they are consumed)

A lot depends on what your application actually does.  When your program gets an OOME I suggest you get a heap dump and analyse it and look for collections (e.g. queue) which are consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer. IO speed was one of the first suggestions. The cluster is much slower, and this explains the much slower initialisation than my on own machines. However the program, once running, does not read/write to disk until the very end (5 hours later), and writes one line in one file when it does. I should also say, there is no one else running anything on the cluster during these tests. I shall look into the heap dump, but in the mean time, any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are simulating a cluster, do you have any network IO, even over loopback? The speed data can be transferred over loopback and vary dramatically by processor and OS.

Comment: The entire job (a single job) is executed on a single cluster node: the idea is to run several hundred such jobs at once. There is no communication between nodes required, each job is entirely self-contained as its own java process.

Comment: How does it simulate a cluster if it uses no IO? Are you saying the each node is entirely CPU bound?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've confused you. Its not simulating a cluster, its running **on** a cluster: a collection of powerful machines (cluster nodes) intended for doing mass experimentation. The nodes share disk space, hence the possible issue of slow IO that I dont think is the root cause. Clusters can run jobs that span several nodes (which is what I thought you were asking after, IO between the nodes being the problem), but the specific jobs Im running are standalone java programs. I can run them on my machines just as on the cluster. The difference is the cluster can run hundreds simultaneously

Comment: I would try running the cluster with just one node and see how the disk behaves e.g. with vmstat or iostat. If the cluster is sharing disk between a 100 nodes, even a small amount of IO can add up.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have to rush off now, but will have a look a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you are using the Server JVM.  The Client JVM is not available on 64 bit machines.  Even if you ask for the Client JVM it will give you the Server one.